# I am trying to pass values from Database to js. But i am getting an error of stepup?

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, servlets

I have got my lat and lng values in database and trying to get them to my javascript on click of a button with id("track"). but the following code throws an error of "stepUp" called on an object that does not implement interface HTMLInputElement. how to solve this

Thanks in advance.

Create.js

```
document.getElementById("track").onclick=function tracking(){
    console.log("Tracking");
    var tname=document.getElementsByName("frname");
    var params ={
            trname:tname,
            bt:"I"  
    }
    $.get("SC",$.param(params),function(responsetext){
        var a=responsetext;
        console.log(a);
    });
}
```

ServerConnect.java

```
if(bt1.equals("I")){
            String tname=request.getParameter("tname");
            String uname=(String)session.getAttribute("uname");
            try {
                cords =requestingclass.getupdatedlocation(tname,uname);
                String lat=cords.get(1);
                String lng=cords.get(2);
                response.setContentType("text/plain");
                response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
                response.getWriter().write(lat);
                response.getWriter().write(lng);
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

requestingclass.java

```
public static ArrayList<String> getupdatedlocation(String tname, String uname) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
        Connection con = ConnectionUtility.connect();
        PreparedStatement ps =con.prepareStatement("select lat,lng from requesttable where requester=? and requested=?");
        ps.setString(1, uname);
        ps.setString(2, tname);
        ArrayList<String> cords=null;
        ResultSet rs= ps.executeQuery();
        while(rs.next()){
             cords=new ArrayList<String>();
             cords.add(rs.getString(1));
             cords.add(rs.getString(2));
        }
        return cords;


    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's this line causing the problem:

```
var tname = document.getElementsByName("frname");
```

`tname` holds an Element object. You then attempt to send it in the data of the request, so jQuery tries to serialise it, causing the problem.

I presume from the context you instead want to get the *value* of the element, so use this instead:

```
var tname = document.getElementsByName("frname").value;
```